# Efficiency of a two-element list

Tags: java, list

I would like to make a program with lists to manage the grades of some school subjects. To do this, I thought of creating a list with two values instead of one. So there would be a list with the grade and the corresponding subject for each node. Subsequently, in order to calculate the average of the grades of a subject, I have to scroll the whole list by averaging all the grades of that subject. However, this method does not seem very efficient since I have to go through the whole list every time. So conceptually, is there any more efficient or more comfortable way to do this program?

Edit:

For example, I could make a single list with all subjects and a list of grades for each subject. So I would no longer scroll through all the grades, but only the grades of the single subject concerned. Would this method be more efficient? Are there other methods always with lists?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Why not have a `Grade` class like `class Grade { int grade; String subject; }` instead? Also, using a `List` you would have to make a `List<Object>` which should raise red flags in your head from one mile away.

Comment: How would you compute an average *without* scanning the whole list, however it is represented?

Comment: @ScottHunter That's right, with my method I have to scan the whole list. I'm thinking if there is a more efficient method.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca For the exercise I must necessarily use a list. So I'm thinking if there is a more efficient method.

Comment: I am not sure if we understand your question, to compute the average of a list of size `n`, you will have to read through all of them atleast once incurring an `O(n)` complexity and is optimal. However, if you have multiple subjects you could have a `Map<Subject, List<Scores>>` but for each `key`, you'll have to read through the entire list to compute the average.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla Thanks for the reply. I have to use one or more lists. If I use a list it is normal that I have to go through the whole list to calculate the average. In your example, what is "map"? Thank you.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla For example, I could make a single list with all subjects and a list of grades for each subject. So I would no longer scroll through all the grades, but only the grades of the single subject concerned. Would this method be more efficient? Are there other methods always with lists?

Comment: Why are you worrying about efficiency? Do you have hundreds of thousands or more students? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." -- Knuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought of creating a list with two values instead of one. So there would be a list with the grade and the corresponding subject for each node.

What you describe, a pairing where one thing leads to its partner thing, is known as a `Map` in Java, also known metaphorically as “dictionary” in some environments.

> However, this method does not seem very efficient since I have to go through the whole list every time. So conceptually, is there any more efficient or more comfortable way to do this program?

No matter how you structure your data, whenever you want to report on your data such as calculating totals or averages, you will need to loop through the data.

If you need to do this reporting multiple times on data that is not changing, and the performance of that looping is proven (not assumed) to have a significant impact on performance of your app, then consider caching a copy of your results in another data structure.

Do not fall into the trap of *premature optimization*. For all the scenarios you have considered, with small to medium amounts of data, efficiency of looping is going to be of no significance bon modern computer hardware.

In object-oriented programming, we usually choose to package our data as objects defined by a class, rather than manage raw data pieces in lists or arrays. I suggest you start by defining a class to hold your student identifier, subject, and grade. Collect objects of that class, then report on that collection.

Tip: In Java 16 due next month, you can use `record` to more briefly write a class whose main purpose is to transparently and immutably carry data. The compiler implicitly provides the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
public record Grade ( UUID studentId , String courseCode , String grading ){}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, you have clarified my ideas a lot. I have to do this exercise for school, and I thought about the two methods I described in the question. The professor told us that the method with only one list is not very efficient and therefore will not be evaluated positively. So I thought about the second method. Obviously in terms of effective efficiency nothing changes, but he wants us to find the best method. So you say to create a list with two values for each node? Thank you.